# what is the advantage of having countable dense subset?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

> what is the advantage of having countable dense subset (for example of the set $L^2([0,1])$, if i have to prove weak convergence ?

edit:

to prove is that every sequence $(f_n)_n$ with $||f_n||_2=1$ has a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$, s.t.

$\int f_{n_k}g \to \int  fg$,$\qquad$ $\forall g\in\ L^2$

Comment: What do you need to prove?

Comment: @Norbert I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution №1.**

> Every bounded sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ have weakly convergent subsequence, provided $X^*$ is separable.

Let $i:X\to X^{**}$ be the natural embedding into the second dual. Without loss of generality $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset B_X$. If $X^*$ is separable, then $(B_{X^{**}},w^*)$ is metriazable. By Banach-Alaoglu theorem it is also compact. Hence the sequence $\{i(x_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset B_{X^{**}}$ have weak-$^*$ convergent subsequence $\{i(x_{n_k})\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. Its weak-$^*$ convergence is nothing more than weak conergence of $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$.

For your case just take $X=L_2([0,1])$ and $x_n=f_n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Solution №2.**

> Every bounded sequence of functionals $\{\phi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset X^*$ on separable normed space $X$ have weak-$^*$ convergent subsequence.

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be countable dense subset of $X$. Since $\{\phi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded so does $\{\phi_n(x_1)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{C}$. So we have  subsequence $\{\phi_n^{(1)}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that converges on $x_1$, clearly this subsequence is also bounded. Assume we have constructed bounded subsequence $\{\phi_n^{(k)}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that converges on $x_1,\ldots,x_k$. Again $\{\phi_n^{(k)}(x_{k+1})\}\subset \mathbb{C}$ is bounded so we have bounded subsequence $\{\phi_n^{(k+1)}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that converges for on $x_1,\ldots, x_{k+1}$. By induction we have constructed a sequence of bounded subsequences $\{\phi_n^{(k)}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with the property that $\{\phi_n^{(k)}\}$ converges on vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_k$. Consider subsequence $\phi_n^\circ=\phi_n^{(n)}$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Clearly $\{\phi_n^\circ\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges for all $x_1,x_2,\ldots$. Since $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is dense in $X$, then $\{\phi_n^\circ\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges on all vectors $x\in X$, i.e. weakly converges on $X$. Thus $\{\phi_n^\circ\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is the desired subsequence.

For your case just put $X=L_2[0,1]$ with $\varphi_n$ defined by $\varphi_n(g)=\int_{0}^{1}f_ng\;d\mu$.

**Note.** Though the second solution looks like functional-analytic it is easily translates to the language of measure theory, but I did not want to do this, just not to hide the main idea of the proof.

Comment: this might be a good proof. but i think there must be a more elementary proof, without dual spaces or Banach-Alaoglu theorem (since these are topics from functional analysis, and the question i asked is from measure theory, integration.).

Comment: @derivative see edits to my answer

Comment: Sorry for the stupid questions, but 1)the boundedness of $\{\phi_n\}$ is not mentioned. Does it come using the Hölder Inequality ? 2) So we showed it for a dense subset, can we neglect the complement set now ? 3) I think you can replace $\mathbb C$ by $\mathbb R$, Thanks.

Comment: 1) In fact $\Vert\varphi_n\Vert=\Vert f_n\Vert$ so $\{\varphi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded in $L_2([0,1])^*$. 2) You  tangled density of the set of functions $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset L_2([0,1])$ with density on the interval $[0,1]$. 3) Yes we can replace $\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{R}$